# div leaving parent when using float

Tags: css

I can't see where's my problem. I've tried multipule ways but I still have the same problem. As the title says, I've got a div into a div. When using float on the child, he leaves the parents div. Even though it's not really the case, when setting borders to check it, that's what I see.

```
#feed{
margin: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
width: 70%;
float: center;  
}

.news{
margin:auto;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
border: 1px solid;
}

.newsContent{
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
background-color:red;
}

.newsContent p{
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.newsDate{
width: 20%;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
float: right;
background-color:red;
}

.newsDate p{
text-align: center; 
}
```

and my html code :

```
<div id="feed">
    <div class="news">
        <div class="newsContent">
            <p> ici nouveauté </p>
        </div>

        <div class="newsDate">
            <p> ici date </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

After the child div, inside the parent div. This clears the float you applied to the child div and should give you the effect you want.

Comment: Great. This article seems to explain floats fairly well, if that helps - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following CSS rule to the parent element (`.news` in this case) should fix it:

`overflow: hidden;`

See the preview here: http://jsfiddle.net/ChAQq/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/QPUzd/1/

It was because of floats properties. You have to be careful with them.

```
#feed{
margin: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
width: 70%;
float: center;  
}

.news{
margin:auto;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
border: 1px solid;
float:left;
}

.newsContent{
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
background-color:red;
    float:left;
}

.newsContent p{
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;

}

.newsDate{
width: 20%;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
float: right;
background-color:red;
}

.newsDate p{
text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: No, actually I just wanted the div to go right in his line. The previous was good. However, I'm sure i'll need yours too ;)